# Make a unittest for a function that uploads a file to S3 using boto3

Tags: python, unit-testing, amazon-s3, boto3

I have this function, that uploads an archive file to S3 bucket:

```
def upload_file_to_s3_bucket(self, bucket, file, key, log):
    if not os.path.exists(file):
        log.error("File '%s' does not exist." % file)
        tools.exit_gracefully(log)
    log.info("Uploading file '%s' to bucket '%s' ..." % (file, bucket))
    try:
        self._s3.upload_file(file, bucket, key)
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        log.error("Unexpected uploading error : %s" % e)
        tools.exit_gracefully(log)
    log.info("Uploading finished.")
```

I want to make a unit test for it and this is what I could write so far:

```
class TestUploadFilesToS3(unittest.TestCase):
    """ Tests unitaires upload_file_to_s3_bucket"""


    def setUp(self):
        conf.LOG_FILE = "/tmp/test.log"
        conf.BUCKET_OUTPUT="name.of.the.bucket"
        conf.Conf.get_level_log()
        self.log = logger(conf.LOG_FILE, conf.LEVEL_LOG).logger
        tools.create_workdir(self.log)
        conf.WORKDIR = os.path.join(conf.LOCAL_DIR, "files/output")
        archive = "file_archive.tar.gz"
        archivePath = "/tmp/clients/file_archive.tar.gz"
        _aws = None

    def tearDown(self):
        tools.delete_workdir(self.log)
        os.remove(conf.LOG_FILE)


    def test_upload_file_to_s3_bucket_success(self):
        self._aws.upload_file_to_s3_bucket(conf.BUCKET_OUTPUT, archivePath, archive, self._log)
```

To make a unit test, I don't know which function Assert should I use in the test function `test_upload_file_to_s3_bucket_success` and what should I exactly compare. 
Can I for example test if the URL of the file exists or not ... ? any ideas?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a clip from a test I wrote for an s3 upload function

```
    self.ti.uploadTemplate(contentsOfFile) # this is what is being tested
    # also supplied from elsewhere "contentsOfFile" and "nameOfFile"
    # bucket is assumed to be called "cloud-test-cf"

    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    mytname = nameOfFile
    obj = s3.Object(bucket_name='cloud-test-cf', key=mytname)
    response = obj.get()
    self.assertEqual(response['ContentLength'], len(contentsOfFile))
    remoteData = response['Body'].read()
    self.assertEqual(remoteData, contentsOfFile)
```

As you can see it does a get on the file immediately after the "uploadTemplate" is used.  If you are using the same region/AZ settings then it should work fine, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel

The unittest method for this test uses a decorator like this

```
@unittest.skipIf(
         not(boto3.session.Config().region_name),
         "aws creds not loaded")
def testuploadTemplate(self):
    #....test code here
```

This decorator means that if the unittest suite is run but AWS keys are not available this particular test is skipped

Comment: Thank you @Vorsprung that's very helping. but I'm getting this error : `==
ERROR: test_upload_file_to_s3_bucket_success (__main__.TestUploadFilesToS3)
ClientError: An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist.
`

Comment: Well in fact, I resolved this error but putting  ̀response = obj.get()` under the upload call. and now I get this error that the test failed because the file and the object from S3 don't have the same length : `   self.assertEqual(response['ContentLength'], len(self.archive))
AssertionError: 141 != 34

`

Comment: Solved. I changed len(contentsOfFile) to os.path.getsize(contentsOfFile)̀

Comment: sorry could have been clearer, in the example "contentsOfFile" is the entire contents of the file as a string.

Answer (score 3):

You can mock interactions with S3 using this library:

https://github.com/spulec/moto

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the botocore [stubber](http://botocore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/stubber.html). There are several examples on that doc page to help get you started.